# Updating comment date using services module

Tags: services

I am trying to update comment date using services Drupal module. I can see that every comment contains following two dates, but I can't update them using command below.

1451929300
1451929703

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-CSRF-Token: khujfk" -H "Cookie: fzuk-uzfk" -X PUT -d '{"nid":"10","created":"1451929400"}' http://url/rest/comment/355
```

I would expect that the creation date would be changed to 1451929400 after running above command, but nothing changes. Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `created` column is protected and cannot be updated via Services. You could create your own custom Service Resource to manually update the time though.